# Can I 'collect' and take ownership of my friends Portuguese registered car that is stuck in UK . I am a portuguese resident

Tags: driving

My friend had to leave her Portuguese registered car in UK and it has been there for more than 6 months. It is still taxed and insured in Portugal, but might have run out of its MOT equivellent. Can I collect it and drive it back to Portugal as a Portuguese resident. If so what documents do I need?

Comment: Where is the car stored? How long has the car been in the UK in total, including the time your friend was using it? For completeness, what is your citizenship? https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/temporary-imports AFAIK the car must be legal and safe for road use in the country where it is registered, meaning it needs a valid MOT; you’ll also need valid car insurance and proof that you have permission from the owner to drive it This is worth a read https://katsgoneglobal.com/how-to-drive-a-foreign-car-in-the-uk/

Comment: The title asks if you can "take ownership," but the question text asks only about possession ("collect and drive back"). Those are different concepts. Which is correct?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has abandoned it and not returned.